# How can I use Graphics2D.drawline with anti-aliasing on a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, antialiasing

[Rough and smooth lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K51sE.png)

[image]

When drawing on a `JPanel`, I can set anti-aliasing on as a rendering hint and then draw a line that has smoothed edges.

If, however, I create a `BufferedImage` and draw the same line on it with anti-aliasing, and then I use `JPanel.drawImage` to draw the buffered image, the line is drown roughly (e.g. anti-aliasing=off).

I can't determine how to draw a line on a buffered image with anti-aliasing.  Can someone clarify how this is done?

In the below example, I'm simply creating two `JFrame`. In one frame I create a panel and draw on it directly. In the other frame I create a panel, then a buffered image that I draw on, then use `JPanel.drawImage` to display. I want the line shown in the buffered image to be drawn with anti-aliasing.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        doDirect();
        doBuffered();
    }
    public static void doBuffered(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("BufferedImage drawn with antialiasing on");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel canvas = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics2D ig2d = image.createGraphics();
                ig2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                ig2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
                ig2d.setRenderingHint(
                        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                ig2d.drawLine(10, 10, 70, 90);
                
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
                g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setEnabled(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void doDirect(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Directly drawn with antialiasing on");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel canvas = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
                g2d.setRenderingHint(
                        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2d.drawLine(10, 10, 70, 90);
            }
        };
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setEnabled(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran your sample and both methods of drawing seemed to apply the antialiasing.  I wonder if it could be a bug in the version of the jdk you're using?  I'm running on Windows with jdk 1.8.0_77 and also tried with jdk 1.7.0_79.

Comment: It seems plausible.  The screenshot/machine showing the issue is a Mac running jdk 1.8.0_102-b14.  

I tried the sample code again on a Linux machine running jdk 1.8.0_101-b13 and both lines appear to be drawn the same, with anti aliasing on. 

If you submit your comment as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran your sample and both methods of drawing seemed to apply the antialiasing. It may be a bug in the version of the jdk you're using. I'm running on Windows with jdk 1.8.0_77 and also tried with jdk 1.7.0_79.

Comment: The sample code was being run on a Macbook with macOS Sierra 10.12.3 and jdk 1.8.0_102-b14.  When run on other machines, such as a CentOS 6.6 server with jdk 1.8.0_101-b13, the issue is not observed.

Comment: No difference on Mac OS X 10.11.6 with Java 1.8.0_131-b11 or 1.7.0_55-b13. No difference on Mac OS X 10.12.5 with Java 1.8.0_131-b11.

Answer (score 0):

I reported this bug on the official Java page, but reporting it has not registered yet. Last correct version for Windows was working with `antialias: On`, for `bufferedimage` which are on version 8. There are no more JDK Version 8 builds for Windows in x64. All of the next versions including the last versions: 18 / 19, OracleJDK and OpenJDK have this unaddressed bug.

I speculate that new millennial developers with their new Shaolin Kung-Fu techniques, throw out all the old versions and they build new versions from scratch, in many wrong ways. It is Java from Oracle a way of death for non business applications in 2022? Yes.